# OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to programming and I have this code that I am trying to run in Pyto app on my phone would really appreciate some help! It's a simulation of the Heat Equation in a bar.

```
from numpy import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib . animation as animation

Nx = 100
Dx = 0.01414
Dt = 0.6
KAPPA = 200.

SPH = 900.
RHO = 2700.
cons = KAPPA/(SPH*RHO)*Dt/(Dx*Dx);
T = np.zeros( (Nx,2), float)
def init():
    for ix in range (1, Nx - 1):
        T[ix, 0] = 100.0;
        
    T[0, 0] = 0.0
    T[0, 1] = 0.
    T[Nx - 1, 0] = 0.
    T[Nx - 1, 1] = 0.0
init()
k=range(0,Nx)
fig=plt . figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=False, xlim=(-5, 105), ylim=(-5, 110.0))
ax.grid()
plt . ylabel("Temperature")
plt . title("Cooling bar")

line , = ax.plot(k, T[k,0],"r", lw=2)
plt . plot([1,99],[0,0], "r",lw=2)
plt.text(45,5,'bar',fontsize=20)

def animate(dum):
    for ix in range (1, Nx - 1):
        T[ix, 1] = T[ix, 0] + cons*(T[ix + 1, 0] + T[ix - 1, 0] - 2.0*T[ix, 0])
    line.set_data(k,T[k,1])
    for ix in range (1, Nx - 1):
         T[ix, 0] = T[ix, 1]
    
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,1)
plt.show()
```

When I run the code above in Pyto app I get: 'OSError: [Errno 25] Inappropriate ioctl for device' and it refers me to the line `import matplotlib . animation as animation`. I am not sure if it's a compatibility issue or something else I can fix

Comment: Are you sure you do not have spaces in the import `import matplotlib.animation as animation` Because your code has spaces in there. And also regarding the `ioctl` error, looks like an issue with your serial port connecting to your phone

Comment: Space or no space, it doesn’t fix the error! Not sure what you mean by serial port connection, but I am using my iphone.